# Как разрешить выделение и копирование данных с TableVIew

Tags: java, javafx

Как разрешить выделение и копирование данных с TableVIew в JavaFX? По умолчанию там выделяется только одна строка, которую нельзя скопировать через Ctrl+C

Answer (score 1):

1. Чтобы выбрать несколько строк в таблице, необходимо таблице проставить `tableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);`
2. Чтобы работало копирование - вы должны сами реализовать данный функционал. Для этого необходимо повестить обработку нажатия клавиш для таблицы. Пример кода
   Класс Bean отвечает за то, чем параметризована таблица

   `class Bean {
       String name;
       int count;
   }`

И само созданте таблицы и обработка нажатия

```
TableView < Bean > tableView = new TableView < > ();
tableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
tableView.setOnKeyPressed(e - > {
    if (e.isControlDown() && e.getCode() == KeyCode.C) {
        ObservableList < Bean > selectedItems = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
        //получаем список выделенных строк и копируем их, например - через точку с запятой, как в excel'e
        String copyString = selectedItems
            .stream()
            .map(bean - > bean.name + ";" + bean.count)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
        //далее сохраняем это в буфер обмена
        StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(copyString);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, null);
    }
});
```